# Как правильно написать "мне не все равно" или "мне ни все равно"?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Как правильно написать - "мне не все равно" или "мне ни все равно"?

Answer (score 2):

**Мне не всё равно.**

Действительно, частица НЕ имеет значение отрицания, а не усиления: мне всё равно/мне не всё равно.

Можно только добавить, что встречаются варианты, в которых ***НИ* может иметь двойное значение (совмещение отрицания и усиления)**: на небе (нет) ни облачка; вокруг (нет) ни души; здесь (нельзя) ни проехать, ни пройти; во всех устойчивых выражениях (ни слуху ни духу, ни много ни мало); в местоимениях (мне это ни к чему/ = мне этого не надо).

Еще интересный вариант: При чем тут он? Он здесь **ни при чём**. Пишется усилительная частица, но усиление не очевидно.

Answer (score 1):

НИ частица усилительная, НЕ — отрицательная.

Усиливать тут нечего. Вы отрицаете утверждение, что вам всё равно:

*Мне не все равно.*